# Does Hitman 3 contain nudity?

Tags: hitman-3

So I want to download Hitman 3, but I'm don't know anything about the franchise so I'm worried if it is not appropriate for me, a 14-year-old. Here's a little background on what I can see:

I don't mind blood and action and stuff. My parents let me watch all 3 John Wick movies without having to cover my eyes in any scenes (just for reference). Also, mild swearing is ok, but not 24/7 non-stop swearing. What I am worried about is nudity. My parents do not allow me to watch anything relating to nudity.

Comment: As a reminder, this is not to place to discuss whether violence or nudity is more appropriate for a 14-year-old. The moderators have had to delete many such comments already.

Answer (score 53):

As others have mentioned, ESRB is often a good place to start, especially if you just want a high-level overview with a short, bullet-point list of objectionable content.

If you want something more in-depth, you might try Common Sense Media's reviews. These are targeted at parents, but may also be useful for anyone who may be sensitive to particular kinds of content. See for example [their page on Hitman 3](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/game-reviews/hitman-iii?gate=1), which provides a much more detailed description of *exactly* what sort of content you can expect to see in the game. Note, however, that their reviews do tend to contain spoilers, as it's impossible to discuss a game at this level of detail otherwise. Here's a short excerpt of their "parents need to know" section for that game:

> Players will typically kill far fewer characters in this game than in most M-rated action games, but the assassinations can be quite graphic and intense. Depending on the manner of death, killed characters may bleed, scream, or flail. Some examples include: garroting, getting crushed by a chandelier, being drown in a toilet, and falling from a skyscraper balcony.

The actual review is longer and provides additional context about these scenes, including the morally gray protagonist. It also provides a set of numerical ratings (out of five) for various different kinds of content, such as violence, sex, language, drug use, etc. It also contains a more traditional review (i.e. answering "is the game good?" in addition to "can my kids play it?"), but this segment is rather shorter than what you might expect to find in a typical review.

Finally, readers need to know that [Common Sense Media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Sense_Media#Advocacy_issues) is an advocacy group, which has at times taken positions that I would consider questionable if not problematic. Nevertheless, in my experience, their *reviews* tend to be relatively well-written and fair even though I'm not a fan of their politics. All the same, I would encourage readers to carefully consider the way that their reviews are framed and characterized rather than blindly relying on their numerical scores. It may also be a good idea to read Common Sense's reviews for games which you have already played, and see whether they are consistent with your personal experience with those games.

Comment: Seems like you could have mentioned that in the "Sex" category on common sense, it says "Not Present" for this game.  That seems to have been the main concern here.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @hairydresden: I answered the question as it was phrased in revision 2.

Answer (score 33):

You can search the [ESRB](https://www.esrb.org) site for game titles to see details on their ESRB ratings.

Here's the page for Hitman 3:

[Hitman 3 (ESRB)](https://www.esrb.org/search/?searchKeyword=hitman%203&platform=All%20Platforms&rating=E,E10+,T,M,AO&descriptor=All%20Content&pg=1&searchType=All)

As you can see, it lists blood, drug references, intense violence, and strong language, but it doesn't mention any nudity.

Answer (score 15):

It was rated M by ESRB for:

> - Blood
> - Drug Reference
> - Intense Violence
> - Strong Language

From:

- [HITMAN 3 - ESRB](https://www.esrb.org/ratings/37421/HITMAN+3/)

Nudity isn't listed.